# UIAlertController is disappearing automatically after short time

Tags: swift, uialertview, uistoryboardsegue

If a textfield is empty, I would like to make an `UIAlertController` to remind, that something has to be filled out in the textfield. Now I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func saveDetails(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    let dController = segue.source as? EntryTableViewController

    if let text = dController?.bezeichnungTextField.text, text.isEmpty {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No description", message: "Please fill out description", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {

    guard let menge = dController?.mengeTextField.text, let bezeichnung = dController?.bezeichnungTextField.text, let kategorie = dController?.categoryButtonOutlet.titleLabel?.text else {return}

    self.saveItem(menge: menge, bezeichnung: bezeichnung, kategorie: kategorie)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now actually it works when I press the button to return to the first controller. But the `UIAlertController` only appears for a very short moment and then disappears automatically. Is there a mistake in my code or isn't it possible to call the `UIAlertController` on a `unwind segue`?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just show the alert controller and then immediately unwind. The solution is to check for the empty textfield before unwinding.

Make IBAction for your button then check the textfield if it is empty and then perforn your segue programmatically.

Comment: I should unwind my segue to get back to the first viewcontroller. How do I have to set the unwind segue in my IBAction programatically?

Comment: You need to have IBAction for your button and inside that function you need to check the textfield and then perform the segue using `performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegue", sender: nil)` [This](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/) tutorial shows exactly how you would do this. Hope it helps